# Ubuntu /etc/hosts addresses in the form *.*.*.*

Tags: ubuntu, hosts

Let's say a website does not have a domain name like `www.google.com` and the only way to connect to it is to use an IP address like `216.58.212.68`. If I add an entry in `/etc/hosts` that looks likes `0.0.0.0 216.58.212.68`, will it block connections to that website? Would a web browser be blocked from visiting it too?

Additionally, would this also apply to local addresses like `192.168.0.1`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. The hosts file doesn't affect any routing.  It only affects name lookups.  Since `216.58.212.68` is an IP address, the system won't look it up in the hosts table.

Read here for more info on the hosts file: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/hosts.5.html

If you want to block connections to an IP address from your system, there are a couple of ways to do that, like:

1. Blackhole traffic using the `route` command:

   ```
   route add 216.58.212.68 gw 127.0.0.1 lo
   ```
2. Reject traffic using the `route` command:

   ```
   route add -host 216.58.212.68 reject
   ```
3. Null route using the `ip` command:

   ```
   ip route add blackhole 216.58.212.68/32
   ```

Now, if you want to block traffic to a system by name, you can add a fake entry to your hosts file pointing that name to the loopback address:

```
127.0.0.1    badactor.evil.com
```

Then any traffic trying to get to that host from your system will be faked out – as long as your system is set to use the hosts file lookup prior to DNS.  Any specifically DNS based lookups will still work, although you could use a DNSMASQ server like a [Pi Hole](https://pi-hole.net/) to block even DNS lookups.

Make sure you read the man pages for the `route` and `ip` commands, so you'll understand how to make these commands persistent across reboots if you need them to be.